# CQWP - dynamically setting the list

Tags: list, content-query-web-part

I have a Webpart that extends the content query webpart, that is currently pointed to List X. 
On the click of a button I want that webpart to be changed to point to List Y.

This seems like a very simple requirement, but it apparently isn't :) 
Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried:

- Changing the ListGuid property
- Changing the ListName property
- Changing ListOverride property (I didn't do this correctly, as it
  just threw an error :) )

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep in the ether of the interwebs I discovered this gem: 
http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/10/retarget-content-query-web-part/

To solve the problem the following code is required:

```
//set the web url    
cqwp.WebUrl = list.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
//set the guid of the list
cqwp.ListGuid = list.ID.ToString();
//set the list title
cqwp.ListName = list.Title;
```

This allows changing the list the CQWP is pointing to :)

I hope this helps someone!